# Can I get Lifetime Learning Credit as a nonresident alien if I am a resident alien for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, credit, education

I have been in the US for 8 years as an F1 student and I am a nonresident alien, but I am a resident alien for tax purposes. Can I claim LLC?

Answer (score 0):

While many credits are not available to non-residents for tax purposes, very few explicitly require specific immigration status.

Specifically, for LLC to be considered an eligible student, you have [to meet these requirements](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/llc):

> Who is an eligible student for LLC?
>
> To be eligible for LLC, the student must:
>
> - Be enrolled or taking courses at an eligible educational institution.
> - Be taking higher education course or courses to get a degree or other recognized education credential or to get or improve job skills.
> - Be enrolled for at least one academic period beginning in the tax year.

No citizenship requirement.

You can check your eligibility [here](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/am-i-eligible-to-claim-an-education-credit).